# Java class casting with generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

i get a Java type mismatch at the following code. For a better reading i skipped the class bodies.

```
class Main{

  //interface
  public interface HasDeletedFlag {
    public boolean deleted_flag();
  }

  //classes
  public abstract class Entity<? extends Entity.Factory<E, ?>>> {
    ...
  }

  public class Select{
    ...

    public <E extends Entity<? extends Entity.Factory<E, ?>>> List<E> search (E.Factory<E,?> result_factory){
      ...
    }
  }

  public static class Person extends Entity<Person.$.Factory>
     implements HasDeletedFlag {
    ...
    public static class $ {
      public static class Factory
        extends Entity.Factory<Person,Factory>{
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  static class Database{
    ...
    public final Person.$.Factory person = new Person.$.Factory();
  }

  //method
  private <E extends Entity<?> & HasDeletedFlag> List<E> findEntity(String id){

    ...
    Database db = new Database(); 
    List<E> objects = new ArrayList<E>();
    Select query = new Select();
    objects = query.<Person>search(db.person);

  }
}
```

In the following line i get the class mismatch error:

```
objects = query.<Person>search(db.person);
```

If i add a class cast like `(List<E>)` the error disappears, but in my understanding the type Person matches the type E.

Greetings
Goetz

Comment: what is ```db.person```? Could you post an MCVE?

Comment: I think,In the call *objects = query.<Person>search(db.person)*; the search() method is returning List<E>,It may be the reason for the error when <Person> was there.

Comment: Generics are invariant, ```List<E>``` does not match ```List<Person>```. Probably best here is to use: ```List<E> objects = new ArrayList<>(query.<Person>search(db.person));```.

Comment: i've edited the post, so the db.person object get be a bit clearer.

@Jorn: i tested your suggestion, but the same error occured.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot that ```E``` might be a subtype or sibling of ```Person```. Any way, here is an [MCVE](https://ideone.com/AcGPfz). Honestly, casting seems fine in this case...